# Are digits in JavaScript regarded as chars?

Tags: javascript, regex, digits, chars

Given the following Regular Expression in JavaScript:

```
56\d.*
```

Above would match e.g. 45678. So my Question is: are digits in JavaScript chars?

*d Matches any single digit, . Matches any char except newline, * matches zero or more occurrences*

Comment: have you tried using it?

Answer (score 3):

Digits in JavaScripts, in a string context, are chars.

The dot in a Regular Expression matches *every* character, except for newlines. If you need a RegExp which matches every character, use `[\S\s]`, which means "every non-whitespace character + every whitespace character" (=everything).

Comment: There are no 'chars' in javascript.

Comment: @kennebec Char is an abbreviation for character. I'm sure that the OP isn't referring to a "Char" datatype.